# Relacionamento circular com EntityFramework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Preciso relacionar a entidade Pessoa com PessoaCadastro usando o EF Core, mas está dando o seguinte erro no Migrations:

> "The navigation property 'PessoaFilial' cannot be added to the entity type 'PessoaCadastro' because a property with the same name already exists on entity type 'PessoaCadastro'."

Preciso que o relacionamento fique dessa maneira no banco:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
public class Pessoa
{
        public int PessoaId { get; private set; }

        public virtual PessoaNatureza PessoaNatureza { get; set; }
        public virtual PessoaFisica PessoaFisica { get; set; }
        public virtual PessoaJuridica PessoaJuridica { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<PessoaCadastro> PessoasCadastros { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PessoaCadastro> PessoaCadastroPessoasFiliais { get; set; }

        public static Pessoa CreateNew (int pessoaId, PessoaNatureza pessoaNatureza)
        {
            return new Pessoa
            {
                PessoaId = pessoaId,
                PessoaNatureza = pessoaNatureza                
            };
        }
    }


}
```

---

```
public class PessoaCadastro
{
        public int PessoaId { get; private set; }
        public int Id { get; private set; }
        public DateTime DataInclusao { get; private set; }


        public virtual PessoaTipo PessoaTipo { get; set; }
        public virtual Pessoa Pessoa { get; set; }
        public virtual Pessoa PessoaFilial { get; set; }

        public static PessoaCadastro CreateNew(int pessoaId, int id, Pessoa pessoaFilial, DateTime dataInclusao)
        {
            return new PessoaCadastro()
            {
                PessoaId = pessoaId,
                Id = id,
                PessoaFilial = pessoaFilial,
                DataInclusao = dataInclusao
            };
        }
    }
```

---

```
public class PessoaCadastroMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<PessoaCadastro>
{
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<PessoaCadastro> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("PessoaCadastro");

            builder.HasKey(pc => new { pc.Id, pc.PessoaTipo, pc.PessoaId, pc.PessoaFilial });

            builder.Property(pc => pc.PessoaTipo)
                .HasColumnName("PessoaTipoId")
                .HasColumnType("int")
                .IsRequired();

            builder
                .HasOne(p => p.Pessoa)
                .WithMany(p => p.PessoasCadastros)
                .HasForeignKey(p=> p.PessoaId)
                .IsRequired();

            builder.Property(pc => pc.PessoaId)
                .HasColumnName("PessoaId")
                .HasColumnType("int")
                .IsRequired();

            builder
                .HasOne(p => p.PessoaFilial)
                .WithMany(p => p.PessoaCadastroPessoasFiliais)
                .HasForeignKey(p=> p.PessoaFilial)
                .IsRequired();

            builder.Property(pc => pc.PessoaFilial)
               .HasColumnName("PessoaFilialId")
               .HasColumnType("int")
               .IsRequired();
        }
    }
```

O que preciso mexer em meu mapeamento para que funcione?

Comment: Esses relacionamentos são assim mesmo, qual a finalidade?

Comment: Sim, são. Tenho mais tabelas envolvidas, mas seria desnecessário citá-las aqui.  A tabela PessoaCadastro deverá armazenar os Códigos (Id) dos meus Clientes, Fornecedores, Filials, Transportadoras, etc. Ela armazena tb, o Código da Filial (PessoaFilialId) para que eu saiba de qual filial pertence o cadastro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basicamente pelo modelo da sua pergunta (*e consequentemente pela comentário que diz que as outras entidades não são necessárias citar*) o modelo funcional de configuração é:

***Models***

```
public partial class Pessoa
{
    public Pessoa()
    {
        PessoaCadastroPessoa = new HashSet<PessoaCadastro>();
        PessoaCadastroPessoaFilial = new HashSet<PessoaCadastro>();
    }

    public int PessoaId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PessoaCadastro> PessoaCadastroPessoa { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PessoaCadastro> PessoaCadastroPessoaFilial { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public partial class PessoaCadastro
{
    public int PessoaId { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int PessoaFilialId { get; set; }
    public int? PessoaFuncInsclusao { get; set; }

    public Pessoa Pessoa { get; set; }
    public Pessoa PessoaFilial { get; set; }
}
```

---

***Configurações:***

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Pessoa>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasKey(x => x.PessoaId);
        entity.Property(x => x.PessoaId)
            .UseSqlServerIdentityColumn();                
        entity.Property(e => e.Nome)
            .HasColumnType("nchar(10)");
    });

    modelBuilder.Entity<PessoaCadastro>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasKey(e => new { e.PessoaId, e.Id, e.PessoaFilialId });

        entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnType("nchar(10)");

        entity.HasOne(d => d.PessoaFilial)
            .WithMany(p => p.PessoaCadastroPessoaFilial)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.PessoaFilialId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);

        entity.HasOne(d => d.Pessoa)
            .WithMany(p => p.PessoaCadastroPessoa)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.PessoaId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);
    });            
}
```